# Image of invertible ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is it true that invertible ideals transform to invertible ideals through ring epimorphisms?

My try: let $ f: R \to S$ be a ring epimorphism. Any ideal of $S$ is of the form $ f(I)$, for some ideal $I$ of $ R$. Also, an ideal $I$ of $R$ is invertible if $ II^{-1}=R$, where $I^{-1}=\{x\in Q(R) \mid xI\subseteq R\}$. (Here, $Q(R)$ is the total ring of quotients of $R$.) Now, if $f(I){f(I)}^{-1}=S$, then we are done. In fact, we should prove that $f(I){f(I)}^{-1}=f(II^{-1})$.

Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "transform to"? The image of an ideal is, in general, not even an ideal. Is your conjecture something like "an ideal that is generated by the image of an invertible ideal is invertible"?

Comment: Along those lines, do you mean ''surjective ring homomoprhism'' instead of epimorphism? It's not true in general that any ideal of $S$ is the form of $f(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$; take the ring epimorphism where $R = \mathbb{Z}, S = \mathbb{Q}$, and $f$ is the inclusion map, for instance.

Comment: Ah! If you mean $f$ to be a surjective ring homomorphism, as Alex Wertheim suggests, then the image of an ideal *is* an ideal, and every ideal $J$ in $S$ is of the form $f(I)$ for some ideal $I$ (actually, $f^{-1}(J)$) in $R$. Now we're talking ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, I mean $f$ to be a surjective ring homomorphism. And by "transform to" I mean whether $f(I)$ is invertible when $I$ is so.

Comment: @Alex: contrary to what you write it is true that every ideal $J$  of $\mathbb Q$ **is**  of the form $J=f(I)$ simply because necessarily $J=0$ !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: What about $J = \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Dear @Torsten: you are right, but for non surjective morphisms of rings the image of an ideal is not even an ideal in general . In the case of $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q$ every ideal  $J\subset \mathbb Q$ is *generated* by the image of an ideal  $I\subset \mathbb Z$ i.e: i.e.$J=I^e=I\cdot \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Dear @Georges: certainly, we are in agreement. I only meant to point out that (as you and Torsten say) the image of an ideal need not be an ideal in general, even if the ring morphism in question is an epimorphism, with Torsten's example of $J = \mathbb{Q}$ in mind for the example I cited. In that case, if one considers extensions of ideals, then there is no problem.

Comment: I'm very happy that we agree, dear @Alex!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Is it true...": NO!
Take for $f$ the quotient morphism $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.
 The invertible ideal $I=2\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$ is sent to $f(2\mathbb Z)=\{\bar 0\}\subset \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which is obviously not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, I conjectured that the image of an invertible ideal under a surjective ring homomorphism is either zero or it is invertible. Right?